# .opera Folder keeps popping up in Downloads folder

Tags: windows-10, opera

About a month ago while installing software, I was inattentive and reckless and accidentally pressed the "Install Opera" Option on during the Software install.

After noticing, I immediately uninstalled Opera with the "Add or Remove Programs" Utility and afterward checked that there were no Opera Folders left in 'Program Files' or 'Program Files(x86)'.

But now a .opera hidden Folder keeps returning to `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Downloads`, despite me deleting it every time I notice its recurrence.

If anyone could help me get rid of opera or whatever is causing the stupid folder to appear I would be very gratefull, as it has become quite a thorn in my eye.

Comment: My first guess would be that the innstallation created a scheduled task to check for updates and the task was not deleted with the uninstall. So take a look in Task Scheduler for starters.

Comment: @KeithMiller Jup that was probably it! I found a OperaAutoUpdate Task in Task Scheduler and removed it now, so I hope that fixes it. Thanks for the Help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remove tasks related to Opera from the task scheduler in Windows to stop the automatic creation of that folder.
Just search for "Task Scheduler" in your Windows search bar. Then in the task scheduler library, you'll be able to see all the tasks which are scheduled to run on Windows. From here, delete all those tasks which are related to Opera browser and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the Opera Browser again and install **Revo Uninstaller** and **C Cleaner**. Using Revo Uninstaller, uninstall the Opera Browser completely and run the Advance
Uninstall afterward (from Revo Uninstaller). It will allow you to deep clean/delete all files, folders, and leftovers.
Then use **C Cleaner** to clean junk registeries. I hope it will solve your problem.